# HTML standalone with Browserify

Tags: javascript, html, browserify

I'd like to use a [browserified standalone bundle](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage) in an HTML page this way:

```
<script>
    window.browserify_standalone.doAwesomeStuff();
</script>
```

*NB: I don't use any module system, that's why I expect the standalone to be accessible from `window`. Let's call the standalone module `browserify_standalone`.*

I want this HTML to be standalone itself (no external js source), so I attempted to write the contents of the generated bundle in a script tag like:

```
<script><%= browserify_standalone_js_content %></script>
<script>
    window.browserify_standalone; // undefined
</script>
```

But there's no way to resolve `window.browserify_standalone` from my page! Surprisingly, importing the originally bundled file the "regular way" works:

```
<script src="browserify_standalone.js"></script>
<script>
    window.browserify_standalone; // Is now defined !
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

*I remarked that the contents of the main file of the module wasn't even evaluated when pasting the script: I placed an `alert()` call inside and got the actual alert only when loading the script from `<script src="..."></script>`*

Which mechanism makes this difference?

Comment: What's interpreting the `<%= browserify_standalone_js_content %>` and is it doing anything to the content, like HTML-escaping it or sanitizing it somehow?

Comment: It's a replacement pattern for [gulp-template](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-template). The rendered html file actually contains the browserified bundle. Do you think some behaviour could have been altered by doing this way?

Comment: It would be worth looking at the final output and seeing what is actually being inserted into the page. As http://stackoverflow.com/users/1034448/jmm mentioned, it's probably being escaped somehow.

Comment: OK guys I gave this a try. Contents perfectly match, including line feeds =/

Comment: Can you create an uber-minimal test case that demonstrates this by posting the HTML source of both versions on something like jsfiddle? Also what is the actual name of your module?

Comment: I eventually understood the issue and posted an appropriate answer. @JMM pasting my code in JSFiddle prompted me that it shouldn't contain HTML which really helped me, so thank you and thanks to everybody who took time to help me on this one !

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've put the scripts into the body tag. Script tag with src attribute get executed once the script is available while inline js gets executed inmediately. So the script tag with src is evaluated after your inline script while two inline script are evaluated in the order in which they are defined.

Comment: Actually the inline pasted script is inserted at the end of the `body` tag and I still have the difference. Moreover I noted that the contents of the main file of the bundled module wasn't executed by testing based on some `alert()` call. I'll mention that in my question

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the heck out of it.

The difference between inline js and `src`-imported js is just XML.

Indeed, if there is something that looks like XML/HTML in the js (even in strings), the inline HTML will break because the `<script>` tag will stop being interpretated. My browserified module bundled an XML parser, which explains the issue.

Nevertheless I've found a not-so-good-looking solution but that works:

*Code to preprocess the JS file to inline:*

```
var browserify_standalone_js_content = encodeURIComponent(fs.readFileSync('browserify_standalone.js').toString())
    .replace(/'/g, '\\\'');
```

*Then evaluate the escaped code in the HTML:*

```
<script>
    eval(decodeURIComponent('<%= browserify_standalone_js_content %>'
        .replace(/\\'/g, '\'')))
</script>
```

*The trick:*

1. Escape special characters from the file's content with `encodeURIComponent` (for `<`, `>`, `\` **and new line characters**)
2. Escape quotes in order to paste the code as a string in the html
3. Reverse operations client-side to read the inline script correctly

I hope this could be useful to some of you :)